# Is it possible to loop creating a tapgesture on images?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have loop creating images on the scrollVIew and i need to control the action when clicking on each image. I heard that the tap gesture can set on the image but i don't know how to set the tap gesture to the image that i created before by looping. is it possible to create the tap gesture on each image in loop? How?

Answer (score 1):

The same functionality in Swift would be,

```
@IBOutlet weak var img1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var img2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var img3: UIImageView!
let imgs = [img1, img2, img3]

for (index, img) in images.enumerated() {
 img.tag = index
 let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
 img.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
 img.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}


@objc func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        let img : UIImageView = tapGestureRecognizer.view as! UIImageView
        switch(img.tag) {
        {
          case 0:
           //your code
           break;

           ...
        }
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
{
  UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"]];
 [img setTag:i];
 img.frame= //set frame accordingly;
  img.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tap =
[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[img addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[tap release];
[scrollView addSubView:img];

}

- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer  {
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)recognizer.view;

      switch([imageView tag])
    {
       case 1:
          //do your work
          break;
       .
       .
       .
       .
       case n:

    }
}
```